# Do I have to use Filebeat to parse logs with logstash?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

I was under the impression that Filebeat is only necessary if I wish to provide a constant, paced, fresh input to logstash.

But the tutorial [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html) starts with configuring Filebeat to send log lines to logstash....

I am confused. I am a total newbie rookie to ELK and I don't understand why Filebeat is needed if I used the '`file {}`' input in the `logstash.conf`.

Could you please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't *have to* use Filebeat if you choose to use the `file` option.

You can easily test this using the following conf file:

```
input {
  file {
  path => "/var/log/debug.log"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
}
```

Upon starting `logstash -f /path/to/your/test.conf`, you will see on your stdout console the contents of your debug.log input file, formatted into JSON fields.